# I need a 2 bytes file that contains 2 digit number

Tags: unix, vim, echo

This is probably a really dumb question, but I was trying different stuff without success.
I need a file that contains a 2 digit number (12 for example) this file it only need to have a size of 2 bytes.
I tried to create a file with echo, vim and sad, but I only got 3 bytes of size, can someone please explain why?

Comment: Also `echo -n 12 >numfile` will work, the `-n` option will omit the newline from the `echo` output. (Some shells have an `echo` that doesn't take a `-n` argument, but most of those you will find, such as bash or zsh, should have one that does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is with the line feed that gets created with echo and this will create an additional byte. Use printf instead and so:

```
printf "%i" "12" > numfile
```

Answer (score 0):

`vim`: set options `binary` and [`noendofline`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27endofline%27) and save the file

```
:set binary noendofline
:w
```